# Extension a divisor on the fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $f: X \to Z$ is a fibration with nice properties ($X,Z$ smooth, semis-table, etc.). Let $0 \in Z$ be a **general** closed point and $X_0$ be the fiber over $0$. If $D_0$ is a Cartier divisor on $X_0$, then is there a Cartier divisor $D$ on $X_U$ such that $D|_{X_0} = D_0$, where $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$?

**Remark.** As commented by abx, it is necessarily to require $0 \in Z$ a general point. Moreover, it is possible to extend **curves** on $X_0$ to $X_U$ by Proposition 12.2.5 (this need $0$ to be a very general point) in "Classification of Three-Dimensional Flips".

Comment: Simple answer is, in general no.

Comment: To expand a little bit Mohan's answer: this is already false for a smooth family. 
For instance, there exists a family of quartic surfaces where some fiber $X_0$ contains a line, while the general fiber does not. This line does not extend to a neighborhood.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question by requiring $0$ is a general point (this can be guaranteed by Noetherian induction in my case). In this case, curves can be extended, how about divisors?

Comment: What is a general closed point?

Comment: I mean "there exists a closed set $Z$, such that for any point $0 \in X\backslash Z$, any divisor on the fiber of $X_0$ extends".

Comment: That's false in general. Take for $X\rightarrow Z$ the universal family of quartic surfaces. The point $z$ such that the surface $X_z$ contains a curve which is not a hypersurface section form a countable union of divisors in $Z$. Such a curve does not extend in a neighborhood of $z$.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by "not a hypersurface section" -- aren't quartics hypersurface? Besides, why such curve does not extend?